# How to fetch and print the list sequentially in a list given from a input file

Tags: python, json

For a specific scenario I am using combination of list append and extend to get a desired output, but it does not give the expected output. The below code gives the output `[['test1', 'test2'], 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', ['test5', 'test6']]` where as I am expecting `[['test1', 'test2'], ['test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6'], ['test5', 'test6']]`. In case I want to change the key (tire1, tire2, tire3) order it should print the output in the new order.

Any tips/suggestion would really be helpful. Thanks

input.json

```
{
    "tire1": {
        "source": [ "{{ 'PEP' | YYYYYYY | join }}" ]
    },
    "tire2": {
        "source": [ "{{ 'REP, DEP' | LLLLLL | join }}" ]
    },
    "tire3": {
        "source": [ "{{ 'DEP' | LLLLLL | join }}" ]
    }
}
```

data.json

```
{ 
    "PEP": {
        "tire2": {
            "tire3": {
                "compname": "test1"
            },
            "tire4": {
                "compname": "test2"
            }
        }
    },
    "REP": {
        "tire2": {
            "tire3": {
                "compname": "test3"
            },
            "tire4": {
                "compname": "test4"
            }
        }
    },
    "DEP": {
        "tire2": {
            "tire3": {
                "compname": "test5"
            },
            "tire4": {
                "compname": "test6"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

test.py

```
import json
import re
def findkeysvalues(inputDict, key):
    if isinstance(inputDict, dict):
        if key in inputDict:
            yield inputDict[key]
        for j in inputDict.values():
            for x in findkeysvalues(j, key):                
                yield x
def process_JSON_value(jsonFileInput, parentInputKey, key):
    with open(jsonFileInput) as jsonFile:      
        data = json.load(jsonFile)
        Dict = { }
        for i in data:
            if i == parentInputKey:
                Dict[i] = data[i]
        return list(findkeysvalues(Dict, key))
def elements():
    with open("input.json") as jsonFile:
        data = json.load(jsonFile)
    lst = []
    rules_items_source = list(findkeysvalues(data, "source"))
    for i in rules_items_source:
        listtostring = ' '.join([str(el) for el in i])
        y = listtostring.split("|")
        x = re.findall("\w+", y[0])
        if len(x) != 1:
            for j in x:
                source = process_JSON_value("data.json", j, "compname")
                lst.extend(source)
        else:
            source = process_JSON_value("data.json", x[0], "compname")
            lst.append(source) 
    print(lst)

elements()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your if block to this code:

```
if len(x) != 1:
            source = []
            for j in x:
                source.extend(process_JSON_value("data.json", j, "compname"))
            lst.append(source)
```

Output with your current input.json

```
[['test1', 'test2'], ['test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6'], ['test5', 'test6']]
```

And if I add extra value to input.json like this:

```
"tire2": {
        "source": [ "{{ 'PEP, REP, DEP' | LLLLLL | join }}" ]
    }
```

Then output:

```
[['test1', 'test2'], ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6'], ['test5', 'test6']]
```